# Replace values using loc command

Tags: python, pandas

There's a dataframe and I need to `replace` values above 512 with 263.

So, I used this code line to filter my indexes first:

```
df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare'].astype(int)
```

Here is the result of this:

```
258     512
679     512
737     512
1234    512
Name: Fare, dtype: int64
```

This looks good! as it filtered all the 4 rows with a value above 512.
Now I need to replace this value with 263:

```
df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare']=df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare'].astype(int).replace({512:263},inplace=True)
```

But it doesn't change anything in my dataframe.
For instance, when I search for index 737, I found this:

```
df.iloc[737]
```

Result:

```
Age                                35
Fare                          512.329
```

So despite of above codes, the Fare hasn't been changed to 263.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `inplace = True` option.

```
df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare']=df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare'].astype(int).replace({512:263})
```

or simply do not assing.

```
df.loc[df['Fare']>512]['Fare'].astype(int).replace({512:263}, inplace=True)
```

From the [replace docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> inplace : bool, default False
> If True, in place. Note: this will modify any other views on this object (e.g. a column from a DataFrame). **Returns the caller if this is True.**

By now, you are modifing the dataframe inplace, but the assignment operator `=` return the caller, so you are rewriting your edit with the original values.

#### EDIT

Actually in my version (pandas 0.24.0) with `inplace = True` it does not return anything, so the bold sentence above may be version dependent (the docs refers to pandas 0.24.2).

As a side note, filtering the data with `.loc` and then using `replace` is redundant: `.replace({512:263})` will convert values 512 only, no need to select that values before with `.loc`.
If you do:

```
df['Fare'].astype(int).replace({512:263}, inplace=True)
```

you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks Valentino, I didn't see your edit first. Yes you're right, ```.loc``` is pretty redundant here. But when I use your code, I get value error: ```ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer```

Comment: that is because you probably have NaN values in your dataframe (they are considered floats) and you use `.astype(int)`. If you remove `.astype(int)` the error should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

when using `.loc` you want to use `[row, col]` and not `[row][col]`.

try:

```py
df.loc[df['Fare']>512, 'Fare']=df.loc[df['Fare']>512, 'Fare'].astype(int).replace({512:263},inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I didn't know using ```.loc``` needed that kind of format. However, when I use the new format, it returns **NaN** value for those indexes

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you aren't just doing

```
condition = df['Fare'].astype(int) > 512
df.loc[condition, 'Fare'] = 263
```

The `condition` is a boolean series and `.loc` will only assign rows in that series with value `True` to your required value.

Comment: Thanks, but it results in error: ```ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer``` Plus, I think using ```loc``` is more understandable than this code by the way.

Comment: My code is essentially the same as yours except it doesn't use `replace`. I would argue that yours is unnecessarily lengthy, but clearly you have other opinions.

Comment: Right, now I can see that using loc is redundant

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet would be even **simpler**:

```
df.loc[df['fare']>512, 'fare'] = 263
```

The code only replaces the value for column `fare`. If you want to replace multiple column values, this can also be specified inside the square brackets.

The actual syntax from pandas is:

```
df.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value
```